# fetch MySQL column values separately

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my MySQL table:

```
1st row-> 5,3
2nd row-> 4,5,1,3
3rd row-> 1,2
```

How can I fetch these values separately like these:

```
1st row-> 5
1st row-> 3
2nd row-> 4
2nd row-> 5
2nd row-> 1
2nd row-> 3
```

I have tried this one `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users SUBSTRING_INDEX(Following, ',', 1) = Following");` but not working

Comment: you either have to do it with php or some programming/scripting language, or using a stored procedure

Comment: @CodeBird : how to do with php

Comment: It sounds like you should normalize your data instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$desired_array=array();
$query=mysqli_query($db_conn, "SELECT column_with_commas FROM table_name");
$i=0;
while($array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row_array=explode(',', $array['column_with_commas']);
    foreach($row_array as $value){
       $desired_array[$i][]=$value;
    }
    $i++;
}

//var_dump($desired_array);

foreach($desired_array as $key => $value){
    for($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++){
         echo 'row '.($key+1).' : '.$value[$i].'<br />';
    }
}

//echo $desired_array[0][0]; //output the first value of row 1
//echo $desired_array[1][0]; //output first value of row 2
//echo $desired_array[0][1]; //out put second value of row 1
```

Outputs:

```
 row 1 : 5
 row 1 : 3
 row 2 : 4
 row 2 : 5
 row 2 : 1
 row 2 : 3
 row 3 : 1
 row 3 : 2
```

Comment: @learner what do you mean without array, you have to put them in an array then access them inside the array, that's the best way to do it, or else you have to set a variable name for each value which is a **VERY** BAD practice. now you can echo `$desired_array[0][0]` to get the first value of row 1. `$desired_array[1][0]` first value of row 2. `$desired_array[0][1]` second value of row 1 etc...

Comment: no no.. the i'm getting the output like this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )`. how can i get output like this 2 4 5 8 ...

Comment: @learner updated my answer, check out the echoes. You just have to access the values in the array, as the var_dump shows you [0][0] will give 2 [0][1] will give 4 etc...

Comment: i have faced another problem here. these codes repeats again and again. `row 1:2 row 1:4 row 2:2 row 2:4 row 2:4 row 2:5`  should be `row 1:2 row 1:4 row 2:4 row 2:5`. 1st row repeated in 2nd row and 1st and 2nd row repeated in 3rd row, same like every row..

Comment: @Learner Updated the while loop